# Discord.py code is not read/writing JSON file correctly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code to check whether a user is in the table or not:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    id = ctx.author.id
    with open('coins.json') as coins:
        coinData = json.load(coins)

    with open('shop.json') as shop:
        shopData = json.load(shop)

    await client.process_commands(ctx)

    if id in coinData:
        print('exists')
    else:
        coinData["players"][id] = 0
        with open('coins.json', 'w') as coins:
            json.dump(coinData, coins)
```

The JSON file it is reading:

```
{"players": {"325616103143505932": 0}}
```

What happens when someone sends a message:

```
{"players": {"325616103143505932": 0, "325616103143505932": 0}}
```

And it doesn't print 'exists' in console, no matter how many messages the person sends, but it adds the key value pair only twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, a string value and an integer value are different.

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> b = '1'
>>> a == b
False
```

So you should either convert your existing json file to using integer IDs (by removing the quotes) or by using `str()` to convert the integer ID to a string.

Here's using a string conversion (with integers you don't have to change anything, only update your file):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.author.id) # this line
    with open('coins.json') as coins:
        coinData = json.load(coins)

    with open('shop.json') as shop:
        shopData = json.load(shop)

    await client.process_commands(ctx)

    if id in coinData:
        print('exists')
    else:
        coinData["players"][id] = 0
        with open('coins.json', 'w') as coins:
            json.dump(coinData, coins)
```